# Mac Mavericks, where is my developer folder after installing xcode?

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, osx-mavericks

I just installed the latest xcode on my Mac Mavericks. There should be a “Developer” folder created in the root folder.  but I cannot find it.  I am not sure if I installed it incorrectly or the latest version changed the installation path. please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html):

> /Developer No Longer Exists
>
> The simplification afforded by repackaging Xcode 4.3 as a single app
>   bundle eliminates the need for the /Developer directory containing
>   prior versions of Xcode. As a result, the Install Xcode application
>   and the uninstall-devtools command line script are also no longer
>   needed.

Comment: some complements to Xcode are not installed automatically, so you need create manually  /Developer folder and install it there, because some scripts (python) look for files there, example:  /Developer/Extras/Dictionary\ Development\ Kit , used by pyglossary

Answer (score 4):

In your terminal run:

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
```

the output is the Developer folder.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what nerdwaller said, you can now access your developer tools by going to Top Bar -> XCode -> Open Developer Tools.